# Tomcat work directory empty

Tags: java, linux, spring, tomcat

My Spring project was successfully deployed on another Linux server. But when I tried deploying it on this Linux server, it won't deploy. When I go to the homepage, I get the error "`HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available`".

I compared the Tomcat directory of both servers and see only differences in the "work" directory. On this server (the one having problem), under "`work\Catalina\localhost\MyProject`" directory of Tomcat, I see that it's empty. Turns out that the files got put under "`work\Catalina\localhost\_`" instead. What's causing Tomcat to do this?

In my tomcat log file, I'm getting this:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SampleService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.wdc.hydra.dao.DatatypeDAO com.wdc.hydra.service.DatatypeServiceImpl.datatypeDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SampleDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Sample' defined in class path resource [Sample-dao-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;`

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: so this question is about the ability to deploy your spring application - I would guess that there is a version mismatch

Comment: the title is rather misleading. Instead of describing your question, this already works on an assumption.
My guess at your problem is a different version of persistence framework in your tomcat /lib folder between the two different linux servers.

Comment: I have a script that I run to set up Tomcat. Tomcat works on both servers, but my project was only able to deploy on one server. I compared Tomcat's directory structure of both servers and they are exactly the same (minus some minor differences), except for the "work" directory as I described above.

Comment: As Matthias said, the problem is probably due to differing versions of your persistence framework. The resulting NoSuchMethodError is preventing Tomcat from fully deploying the app - and hence leaving the work directory empty. You say that the directory structure is identical between both installs. Can you confirm that the versions of the persistence jar files are the same? You may have to expand the jars and look at the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file. Specifically the Specification-Version property.

Answer (score 0):

How does the Spring Container defined? whether its by XmlWebApplicationContext / FileSystemXmlApplicationContext / ClasspathXmlApplicationContext and if its through FileSystemXmlApplicationContext then your directory structure in both the linux servers should be same. like wise others too.

Comment: It's by XmlWebApplicationContext.

Comment: Hmm.. I feel its because the classpath of jar files. If your are using  JPA provider like hibernate, you will see something like Hibernate-jpa<version>, and make sure there is only one in the classpath. Its failing at the JPA level.